# No WinForms como fazer o cursor do datepicker andar ao digitar a data?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datepicker

A pergunta é sobre o controle DateTimePicker do WinForms. Quando digitamos a data, ao invés de escolher pelo calendário, o cursor não anda. Ou seja, digitamos os dois digitos do dia, e ao invés do cursor passar para o mês, ele continua no dia. Se continuarmos digitando ele sobrescreve o valor do dia.

Como eu posso modificar esse comportamento para que ao digitar o dia ele automaticamente passa para o mês e depois para o ano? O objetivo é que ao digitar a data, digitemos por exemplo `06042018` diretamente e ele fique 06/04/2018.

Tentei encontrar alguma propriedade do controle que habilite isso, mas não tem. Também pensei em tentar fazer isso como o evento KeyUp, mas não consegui encontrar nada que defina a posição do cursor.

Como eu posso implementar esse funcionamento no DateTimePicker?

Comment: Quando me pediram algo assim, optei pelo maskedtextbox, mas pelo DateTimePicker é interessante. Vou aguardar caso alguém já tenha feito, caso contrário tento fazer

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução de contorno é utilizar o recurso do `SendKeys.Send()` no evento de `ValueChanged`. Assim cada vez que o valor for alterado em uma das propriedades, a seleção irá navegar para a próxima área.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    {   
        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                SendKeys.Send("{Right}");
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sei que o post é antigo, mas tive a mesma duvida, resolvi ativando a opção em "Mask Settings" => "Use Adavancing Caret".